# Where did the Device Features Programming Guide went to?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

The Event Handling Guide for iOS mentions the Device Features Programming Guide. However, that guide disappeared. Google points to broken links at Apple, which redirects to the iOS Reference Library.

Has this been renamed? Does anyone know the name of that guide now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that it?
http://www.scribd.com/doc/36501376/Device-Features-Programming-Guide

Comment: Yes, but that's from a third party source. I'd like to get it from Apple.